# Correct way to update scope value in angularjs view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

View code

```
 <a ng-click="deleteOrdersUpdate()">Update</a>
 <span class="red">{{noOfOrders}}</span>
```

Controller code

```
 $scope.deleteOrdersUpdate=function () {
 $scope.noOfOrders=$scope.selection.length;
 scope.$apply();
 };
```

I keep getting $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress  error.

What is the correct way to do this?Can any one please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'll add a little explanation to @RonnieTroj 's answer: `ngClick` directive wraps event callback in `$scope.apply`, that's why it is not needed in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if it is already in any digest cycle, if it is then it will be automatically done, you don't need to do this, if not then you can apply the scope

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to call `$apply` here as you're already operating within the angular context.

```
$scope.deleteOrdersUpdate = function () {
     $scope.noOfOrders = $scope.selection.length;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is beacase $apply already in progress.you have to check the phase first .Here is good explanation and implement

[angularjs-apply-digest-in-detail](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/06/angularjs-apply-digest-in-detail-with.html)